# How do I use regular expression/JSON path extracted variables within other variables in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm attempting to use a variable that was previously set either via a 'Regular Expression Extractor' or a 'JSON Path Extractor' in a 'User Defined Variables' node in JMeter.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working.

This is my extractor....

[image]

And this is my user defined variables node attempting to use the variable from the extractor....

[image]

I don't think it matters where it is, as variable scope apparently is at thread level, but I've tried this node both immediately after the regex extractor and in a different future request.

When I attach a debug post processor, these are the results that are returned...

```
signin=a5360708f46ddea1c8491889bb4433d7
signin1=${signin}
signin2=${__V(${signin})}
signin3=${__eval(${signin})}
signin4=${__evalVar(signin)}
```

`${signin}` has clearly been set correctly evidenced by the string value, however none of my substitution attempts have worked.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that User Defined Variables is not updated after the variable is filled in.

So you need to use a [User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) that you will put as a child of the first Sampler following the sampler that contains the Regex Post Processor.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @UBIK LOAD PACK answer,

[User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) set variable at start of the test before Samplers are execute and therefore before `signin` variable is been assign.

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

You should add variables assignment in [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) which will be the child of a sampler after the sampler you assign `signin`,

Noice that if you **don't have Sampler after** you can add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) (with pause 0 ms ) or [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) which won't effect your test and enable you to set variable using `signid` updated value.